# Passing an array from SQL to Swiftmailer

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to pass an array with emails to Swiftmailer so it can send multiple mails at once. The array I should pass to it is: `$to[];`

I am using this code to get the data from DB but it keeps saying `array(0) { }` when I `var_dump` `$to`. No error from the database whatsoever, I tried using mysqli_error and still nothing:

```
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT user_email,user_id FROM users";
                $q = mysqli_query($connection_offerme,$sql);
                if($q){
                    $to = array();
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
                    {
                        $to[] = $row['user_email'];
                    }

                    var_dump($to);
                }
                else {
                    echo "no results";
                    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection_offerme));
                }

                ?>
```

edit: PS. the result I get from this is `array(0) { }` and not **"no results"** plus a sql error

Comment: Could you check var_dump($row) inside the while statement?

Comment: positive, all the mails I need are there in $to[] as I var_dump it inside the loop, but how to proceed now?

Comment: `var_dump($to);` Does this gives you all the emails in an Array? Or this is command is getting failed?

Comment: @Alok when I var_dump($to) inside the loop it does get all the emails from the DB, but when I var_dump($to) outside of the loop, the results are not in the array.

Comment: OMG! Apparently I can not use var_dump(); between if(){} and else{}, because PHP expects a statement. Error was shown in PHPStorm

Comment: What error did PHPStorm show? Is the code you pasted above the real code you are using?

Comment: Yes, it is the real code. PHPStorm just slightly underlined the misplaced code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple: PHP does not allow usage of `var_dump();` function between `if(){}` and `else{}`.

Proper use of the `var_dump();` in my code above would be:

```
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT user_email,user_id FROM users";
        $q = mysqli_query($connection_offerme,$sql);
        if($q){
            $to = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
            {
                $to[] = $row['user_email'];
            }

            var_dump($to); // - VAR_DUMP(); NOT ALLOWED HERE

        }
        else {
            echo "no results";
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection_offerme));
        }
            var_dump($to); // - VAR_DUMP(); SHOULD GO HERE INSTEAD
        ?>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound exactly right. Inside the "if" - that's fine, it's just only going to do it if the "if" condition is met. So, in the context of what you are trying to do, yes - where you have it now is what you need it to do, but to say "php doesn't allow usage of var_dump inside of an if statement" is wrong.

Comment: Since I get a result out of the same "if" condition and I 100% have the if($q) working, it is obvious that php does not allow the usage of var_dump inside of an "if" statement indeed.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what I am saying. In your example above, where you have "not allowed here" - it's ALLOWED there, but it's only going to run the vardump if the "if" statement evaluates to true. The 2nd vardump will ALWAYS run. Logically, yes - it may or may not make sense in an "if", but syntactically it's fine. You are trying to say it is not, which is false.